# Как сделать дату в таком формате 1 January 2020, 2:22pm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, date-fns

у меня приходит дата с бека в таком формате "2020-10-19 10:22:47", каким образом с помощью JS (без использования библиотек, или же с помощью date-fns) я могу получить дату в таком формате:

*1 January 2020, 2:22pm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так

```js
let date = new Date("2020-10-19 10:22:47");

var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric',minute: 'numeric', hour12: true };
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', options));
```